# Can we add attributes to buttons in divi theme?

Tags: wordpress

I want to add a rel="nofollow" attribute to several buttons displayed in my divi theme, however I do not find any such option on the dashboard is there any other way?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this in Divi without using code. It may be easier if you are new to WordPress :)

Step 1: Click the cog icon (settings) on the button.

Step 2: Navigate to advanced in the menu.

Step 3: Scroll down and select attributes.

Step 4: Tick nofollow then save item and update the page!

Answer (score 0):

Try to set ID to button and use script on divi theme integration settings page.

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
  var anchor = document.getElementById("myAnchor");
  var att = document.createAttribute("rel");
  att.value = "nofollow";
  anchor.setAttributeNode(att);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to a *Code* Module on a page, or to the `<head>` of your website via the *Divi > Theme Options > Integration* section of wp-admin:

```
<script>
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
    jQuery('a.et_pb_button').attr('rel','nofollow')
});
</script>
```